# What approach can I use to wait for all child callbacks to complete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to figure out an architecture to allow a parent component, to wait for all the child components to finish rendering and then do some work. Unfortunately in this case I need to do the rendering outside of React and it's done asynchronously instead.

This makes things a little complex. So in my example I want the `doSomethingAfterRender()` function in the *ParentComponent* to be called once, after all the *ChildComponent* `customRender` calls have completed.

I do have one potential solution, though it doesn't feel very clean which is to use a debounce on the `doSomethingAfterRender()` function. I'd much rather use a more deterministic approach to only calling this function once if possible.

I'm wondering if anyone has a better suggestion for handling this?

**ParentComponent.js**

```
const Parent = (props) => {

    // This is the function I need to call
    const doSomethingAfterRender = useCallback(
        async (params) => {          
             await doSomething();             
        },
    );

    // Extend the child components to provide the doSomethingAfterRender callback down
    const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(props.children, (child) => {
        if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
            return React.cloneElement(child, { doSomethingAfterRender });
        }

        return child;
    });

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <...someDOM....>
            {childrenWithProps}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
   
}
```

**ChildComponent.js (this is actually a HoC)**

```
const withXYZ = (WrappedComponent) =>
    ({ doSomethingAfterRender, ...props }) => {

        // I need to wait for this function to complete, on all child components
        const doRender = useCallback(
            async () => {
                await customRender();

                // Call the doSomething... 
                if (doSomethingAfterRender) {
                    doSomethingAfterRender();
                }
            },
            [doSomethingAfterRender]
        );

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <... some DOM ...>
                <WrappedComponent {...props} renderLoop={renderLoop} layer={layer} />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    };
```

**App.js**

```
const Child = withXYZ(CustomWrappedComponent);

const App = () => {
   return {
      <ParentComponent>
         <Child />
         <Child />
         <Child />
      </ParentComponent>
   };
}
```

Comment: Is this possible : in the parent maintain a counter of how many child components have started and a count of how many child components have completed. after every child callback increase completed count by one and check if started_count == completed_count. If started_count == completed count then call doSomethingAfterRender()

Comment: Have the child component return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Save all your returned promises and then you can do [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in your parent

Comment: @CatchAsCatchCan how would I return that exactly? As Functional components need to return the JSX? That's the sort of ideal I'd like to go for

Comment: @Ian I have added a how to.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly. I would do something like: `useState with useRef.`
This way I would *trigger* *only once* the Parent and that is when all Child components have finished with their respective **async** tasks.

Child.js

```
const child = ({ childRef, updateParent }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("Not Set");
   useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof childRef.current !== "boolean") {
      const display = (childRef.current += 1);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setText(`Child Now ${display}`);
          if (childRef.current === 2) {
          updateParent(true);
          childRef.current = false;
        }
      }, 3000);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>Test {text}</div>
    </>
  );
}

const Parent = ()=>{
  const childRef = useRef(0);
  const [shouldUpdate, setShouldUpdate] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shouldUpdate) {
      console.log("updating");
    }
  }, [shouldUpdate]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {childRef.current}
      <Child childRef={childRef} updateParent={setShouldUpdate} />
      <Child childRef={childRef} updateParent={setShouldUpdate} />
      <Child childRef={childRef} updateParent={setShouldUpdate} />
    </div>
  );
}
```